# How to disable a method?

Tags: java

I'm not sure how to put this, but I'm going to try and explain my situation.

I have a java method called exampleFunction() defined in Example1.java. And I have another java file Example2.java. Now Example2.java somehow calls exampleFunction() via other methods defined in other files and so on, and I can't seem to figure out where and how the exampleFunction() is being called.

Is there anyway I can have Example2.java NOT run exampleFunction() at all even if it is called up on? That will save me a lot of time in trying to find where the function is being called.

Comment: You could just comment out `exampleFunction`, and see what breaks?

Comment: step through the code using a debugger

Comment: On the first line of your `exampleFunction`, you can print the stack trace and see where the call comes from: `for (StackTraceElement ste : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
    System.out.println(ste);
}`

Answer (score 7):

On the first line of your `exampleFunction`, you can print the stack trace and see where the call comes from:

```
for (StackTraceElement ste : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
    System.out.println(ste);
}
```

Comment: I will try this now. But the call comes from multiple methods. I want to run exampleFunction() when called from other methods or java files, i just don't want it to run when called from Example2.java.

Comment: @user2263104 The right way is to make sure you don't call the methods that call exampleFunction. If you can't, you could check if one of the methods in the stack trace is in Example2.java, in which case you return from exampleFunction. So in the loop in my answer, you could do something like: `if (ste.getClassName().contains("Example2")) return;` for example. Note: That is really ugly and I would certainly try to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for your input Assylias. I will try that and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just print a stack trace in `exampleFunction` and check it to see who's calling the function?

```
new Exception().printStackTrace();
```